# How to set lable at rightside in ToolBar in gxt

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am having problem to set label at right corner in `ToolBar`.

Hear is piece of code please check it.

```
public class CustomGrid extends ContentPanel {

    private final Grid<ContentItem> grid ;

    public CustomGrid() {
        setHeaderVisible(false);
        setBodyBorder(false);
        setBorders(false);
        setHeaderVisible(false);
        setCollapsible(true);
        setLayout(new FitLayout());

        /* Code...... */

           LabelToolItem item = new LabelToolItem();
           item.setLabel("0 Rows Selected..");

           ToolBar toolbar = new ToolBar();
           toolbar.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
           toolbar.add(item);
           setTopComponent(toolbar);

           add(grid);

    }
    }
```

in above code toolbar displays label in center.

if i give `toolbar.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);` than it display at left corner but, while i give `toolbar.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);` it displays at center. what should i do?, i missing something?

please help me.

Comment: I tried your code snippet. It works for me. Can you tell me which versions of GWT, GXT you are using. Also, the browser in which it is not working. I tried it in GXT 2.2.5, GWT 2.4 and IE 8.0

Comment: i tried in mozila firefox 10.0.2 and GXT 2.2.5 and GWT 2.4, toolbar.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT); will displays in center.

Comment: Ok, it's working. There was my mistake, another css is running on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem trying to right-align a Button in a HorizontalPanel. The solution was to pack the button into a cell and set the align_right on the cell.

```
<g:HorizontalPanel ...>
   ...
   <g:cell horizontalAlignment="ALIGN_RIGHT" width="100">
      <g:Button ui:field="j_logout" text="Log out" width="90%"/>
   </g:cell>
</g:HorizontalPanel>
```

Another solution might be calling `addFill()` on the Toolbar before adding the elements that should go right.